# How to click on the element using jQuery which generates dynamic ID on the click of the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

```
<div class="scrolling-items-wrapper">

  <div class="menu" style="max-height: 105px;">

    <div class="scrolling" style="width: 196px; max-height: 105px;">

      <div class="scrolling-content">

        <ul >
          <li data-menuid="ABC_1">
            <a style="white-space:nowrap;" href="#">
              <span class="checkbox-container" href="#">
                <span class="checkbox" visibility="hidden"></span>
              </span>
              <span>ABC_1</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li data-menuid="ABC_2">
            <a style="white-space:nowrap;" href="#">
              <span class="checkbox-container" href="#">
                <span class="checkbox" visibility="hidden"></span>
              </span>
             <span>ABC_2</span>
           </a>
         </li>
         <li data-menuid="ABC_3">
           <a style="white-space:nowrap;" href="#">
             <span class="checkbox-container" href="#">
               <span class="checkbox" visibility="hidden"></span>
             </span>
             <span>ABC_3</span>
           </a>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Manual click :
Whenever that element is clicked manually it generates a dynamic ID.

Using jQuery :
I want to click a particular element suppose ABC_1 using jQuery.

When it is clicked it should generate the Dynamic ID.

Comment: If the id is to be generated when it is clicked how do you know which one to click?

Comment: dynamic id for the clicked element or a random number which can be used for any other purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
$( "li[data-menuid='ABC_1']" ).click()
```

If it doesn't work here is a list of all jquery selectors: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: The normal click actions are not working on that element as on it works on the static elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you have al element with ID ABC_123, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ABC_123").click(function () {
        var newId = "ABC_"+new Date().getTime();
        this.id= newId;
    });
});
```

This will change the id of the element by adding the date in miliseconds. Then, do what you want with the new ID.

Comment: I just want to click on that element. As its a dynamic ID      $('#ID').find('li').find('a span').trigger('click')   or  .click()  nothing works on that element.